# Quantum superposition and photon polarization

Tags: quantum-mechanics

From what I have understood, if a physical system may be in one of many configurations then the most general state is a combination of all of these possibilities. However, when you measure that physical system, you will get one of these possible states.

I have also read that a photon polarized along the direction $\alpha$ can be written as a superposition of the two states 1) polarization along the x direction and 2) polarization along the y direction. When you measure the photon polarization, you can get a combination of these 2 states (x and y), not only one of the states (x or y).
It seems like this explanation of the photon polarization goes against the concept of quantum polarization.

If the explanation is that when you measure, you can also get the superimposed, then how can, say, an electron be in the superimposed state of spin up and down, if you can't measure that electron and get a state of spin up and down at the same time?

Comment: When the polarization measuring a single photon you have the freedom to choose the axis along which to measure (or more generally the basis, you can for example measure whether the photon is left- or right-handed circularly polarized). But when you do this measurement, you only get one of the answers: along that direction or opposite to that direction and exactly that is the nature of quantum measurement you describe. Where is the discrepancy?

Comment: but what if the photon polarized along the direction α is written as a superposition of the 2 states: polarization along the x and y direction, the answers are not along that direction or opposite to that direction

Comment: Suppose the y-axis is 0 degrees and the x-axis is 90 degrees. Now suppose your photon is at $\alpha = 45 \text{degrees}$. Now suppose you have a polarizer. You're going to allow the photon to hit the polarizer, and you're going to see whether or not the photon gets through. If you align the polarizer along the x or y axes, then you'll have a 1/2 probability of the photon getting through. If you align the polarizer along the $\alpha$ axis, then the photon will always get through.

Comment: As @SebastianRiese correctly stated, individual photons are circularly polarized by spin that points forward or backward. Your error is in thinking that photons are linearly polarized in a direction perpendicular to their movement. This is incorrect. A linear polarization of light is created by an equal number of photons circularly polarized in both directions.

Comment: @DanielSank Why are you referring to a photon polarization as if linear? The "polarization" of a single photon is its spin that points either forward or backward (based on our choice of left and right). Thus individual photons are "circularly polarized". In other words, light with a circular polarization consists of photons with the spin pointing in the same direction.

Comment: @safesphere Your statement is not correct: A single photon can be in a linearly polarized state ($+$ and $-$ label circularly polarized states): $\left|x\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( \left|+\right> + \left|-\right>\big)$ and $\left|y\right> = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \big( \left|+\right> - \left|-\right> \big)$. The point is, that the two possible states you may get in a measurement depend on *the question you ask*, that is, in which polarization basis you do the measurement.

Comment: @SebastianRiese The states are circularly polarized as two possible directions of spin. A "linear" polarization refers to a superposition of states, not a pure state. My comment was about the physical meaning of the photon polarization as its spin. In no superposition of the spin states the resulting spin is perpendicular to the line of movement, is it? (Your formulas don't define the actual $x$ or $y$ directions.) I do see your point though, thanks for the clarification.

Comment: It is a pure state (in the usual sense of the word) that the density matrix is of the form $\rho = \left|\psi\right>\left<\psi\right|$. There is nothing that makes the helicity eigenstates of the photon more real or pure than any other state of the photon. It is just one of the possible bases to measure the polarization in.

Comment: @SebastianRiese What would be the polarization axis for such a photon? Vertical? Horizontal? Any other degree? Where would its spin point? Perpendicular to the photon direction? If I measure the spins of photons of a linearly polarized light, would all photons have the same spin? And what would it be? Certainly not 1 or -1, so fractional? No. So this sure is not a pure state by any definition that is based on the physical meaning. You may not be mathematically wrong, but, if nothing else, you are creating more confusion with an unnecessary extra level of complexity.

Comment: You can't measure the spin state of a single photon unless you know something about it beforehand (e.g. that is either one of perpendicular linear polarizations). But of course the spin of $\left|x\right>$ and $\left|y\right>$ would point in the $x$ or $y$ direction, and there is nothing preventing that. And if I do a measurement of any spin projection I will either get $m=+1$ or $m=-1$. About the linearly polarized light: all photons will be linearly polarized, a mixture $\rho =\frac 1 2 \big(\left|+\right>\left<+\right|+\left|-\right>\left<-\right|\big)$ is quite different: it's unpolarized.

Comment: @safesphere Note: This all connects to the classical case: Just take a look at Landau Lifshits volume II *Classical Theory of Fields*. They provide a description of the polarization of classical light. Now, since the eigenmodes of the Maxwell equations (let's work in periodic boundary conditions) are exactly the photon modes when we quantize (the development coefficients are replaced by the creators/destroyer), you know that any eigenstate of the classical field will be a photon state. (Or stated in another manner: The classical field arises from coherent states of the quantum field).